# Are there materials that would mimic cellular membranes at temperatures as high as 460°C?

Tags: temperature, material-science

A typical mammal cell has a double lipid layer membrane that is hydrophobic on the inside. This is the way cells separate their internal milieu from the external milieu, allowing differences in ion and other solutes concentrations. So even in non-aquatic animals, cells have water inside and outside most of their cells, including neurons for example.

Water having to be liquid to act as a solvent for biological processes, this limits the temperatures allowed for a normal cell to survive especially in the upper range.

Living cells on Earth typically withstand a range of temperatures that is rather narrow in comparison with the variety of temperatures found in the solar system, let alone the entire universe.

Venus surface has a mean (in every sense of the word) surface temperature of about 460°C. This higher temperature and other things prevent Earth organic life from surviving in this environment without special protection, and even machines sent there like the Russian Venera missions, could not survive longer than an hour or two on the surface.

So I am wondering what would it take to create a biology made of other materials yet working on similar principles.

Since the cellular wall is undeniably a critical feature of all life on our planet, I am starting with it instead of, say, DNA.

Basically, water should be substituted with another solvent since it vaporizes at 100°C. I guess this is not impossible to have a solvent liquid at 460°C. At least some materials are liquid at this temperature, but would they have solvent properties is less certain.

Then comes the membrane. Given a solvent withstanding Venus surface temperature, are there materials that would produce something similar to hydrophobia with it? Does the solvent need to be polar?

I look for similar results, not necessarily the same physics.

For those not familiar with biology, a cell membrane is not a static object. Lipids are mostly free to move around the membrane. So this is like a liquid layer sandwiched between two other liquid layers. However,  the thickness of the membrane can be made constant because molecules that form each layer have some sort of legs attracting the legs of the opposite layer, so those molecules move laterally but not in other directions and this way there are always two layers only.

Sidenotes: having found a solvent and a way to make a cell membrane does not even start to build life, obviously. So this question is limited to the feasibility of artificial vesicles (little biological bubble filled with stuff), not entire cells, withstanding 460°C. Also, this is not about judging if life could have emerged on Venus, because I do not ask for a solvent or materials that are naturally found on Venus.

Comment: I suggest rewriting this question to about 1/4 of its length.

Comment: I was answering to your first comment. Regarding the length, I understand why you would ask that, but if I do that I will compromise the understanding by people who may not be familiar with each aspect of the question. I detailed intentionally, also to not make it "too broad" "opinion based" and so.

Comment: And actually you can answer the question without reading the text if all is clear about what a cell membrane is.